# default debug window setting in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I would like to have the default window during a debug session be 'Locals'.

I *think* there a way to do this by blowing away all other devenv settings, but I'm reluctant to do that as the latest R# seems related somehow.

How can I make the Locals window be the default while debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Berryl, I am not really an expert but I hope this helps:

When I am debugging in VS2010, I choose Debug --> Windows --> Local.
That Local windows stays there if I stop and Debug again.

You can also right click this window and choose "Dock as Tabbed Document", which makes it appear as a tab right next to the pages you are currently debugging.